# How to use the /spawnpoint command in 1.9.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering how to use the `/spawnpoint` command in 1.9.4. I tried `/spawnpoint @p -44 7 -28` and it said:

```
Set spawnpoint to -44 7 -28
```

I then used `/kill` but I respawned at my original spawn location and the following message(s) appeared:

```
Killed JohnnyBobMan (Me)
JohnnyBobMan fell out of the world
Your home bed was missing or obstructed
```

When I tried `/spawnpoint -44 7 28` (Not -28), it worked and sent me to `-44 7 28`. This may seem like a solution but remember: It want to respawn at -28, not 28.

Thanks alot for your time.

Comment: Is there anything at `-44, 7, -28` that could obstruct you respawning?

Comment: ah dident think to put that in my awnser good job thinking of that!

Answer (score -1):

Who are you trying to set a spawnpoint to?

If your trying to make a spawnpoint for you, then just go into the desired spawnpoint and do

```
/spawnpoint
```

If this doesn't work my brainz dead sry

Answer (score -1):

just do /spawnpoint yourusername -44 7 -28